# Alternatives to EDTA for calcium ion chelation

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ph, coordination-compounds

Are there any $\ce{Ca^2+}$ chelating agents (other than EDTA) that are as good as EDTA in terms of binding calcium ions and effective in a pH range of $5$ to $9$?

Comment: Hi Smruthi, welcome to Chem.SE! Have you done research on this topic? If so, please share your research on this topic! It will help potential answerers on the extent of your knowledge.

Comment: I don't have time to write an answer now, but this looks interesting, since crown ethers are known for their ion selectivity: https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ac00098a016

Comment: EGTA.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EGTA_(chemical)